# amazon dynamodb 'Invalid UpdateExpression: The expression can not be empty

Tags: .net, amazon-dynamodb

I am seeing some strange behavior regarding the `AWS DynamoDb Client` for `.NET`, I have tried the following two expressions to update a table item but both of them result in the exception.

> Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBException: 'Invalid UpdateExpression:
>   The expression can not be empty;

'

```
{
    "ExpressionStatement": "attribute_not_exists(#K)",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
        "#K": "MantleWebContextVersion"
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {}
}
```

and

```
{
    "ExpressionStatement": "attribute_not_exists(MantleWebContextVersion)",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {},
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {}
}
```

I am wondering if anyone can spot an issue with the above Update expression or if you can direct me to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues here.

First, `ExpressionStatement` is not a valid key. You should be using `ConditionExpression`.

Second, you don't have an `UpdateExpression` e.g. `SET #key1 = :val1`

[Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#API_UpdateItem_Examples)